# iOS animate clipToBounds, masksToBounds, or similar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, calayer, caanimation

I have an image view that starts out cropping it's image with clipsToBounds and content mode set as "scale aspect fill", and I want it to "enlarge" the image to the whole image.  If clipsToBounds=NO was an animatable property, that would be exactly what I want, which it does not seem to be.  Is there a way to animate that?

If not, another way would be resizing the view so it is the same width-height ratio as the image's size, while keeping it no smaller than the image view was to begin with (i.e. minimal increate to height or width, no decrease to either).  I'm not sure the best approach to doing this, considering the image could be much bigger or smaller than the image view, and the image's width-height ratio could be just about anything (but it will usually be an iOS device camera photo).

UPDATE 1: It seems like layer.masksToBounds would work, the documentation says that it is animatable, but my code does not seem to work:

```
CABasicAnimation *layerAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"masksToBounds"];
layerAnim.fromValue = @(YES);
layerAnim.toValue = @(NO);
layerAnim.removedOnCompletion = YES;
layerAnim.duration = 1.0;
[_imageView.layer addAnimation:layerAnim forKey:@"masksToBounds"];
```

I am running this layer animation at the same time as a UIView block animation that is changing the frame and transform of the image view, if that matters.

UPDATE 2: I did not have this core animation in the UIView animation block, which according to the documentation, it should be.  I have moved the above code into the animation block, but it is still not animating (change happens instantly).  I'm beginning to think that "animatable" simply means it can be placed in an animation, not that it will actively animate over time.

Answer (score 2):

So you don't want your image to grow, but you want it to be clipped at first, and then the outer pixels are exposed?

You can do that using Core Animation and a layer mask.

Here's what you do:

Set the image view's clipsToBounds to FALSE, so the image would fully display if you let it.

Create a CAShapeLayer that's the size of the whole image. Create a rectangular bezier path that's the size of the initial image. Install that bezier path's CGPath as the path of the shape layer.

Set the shape layer's fill color to an opaque color

Then install the shape layer as the mask of your image view's layer. That will cause the image to be clipped to the shape of the shape layer.

Now, if you change the path that's installed in the shape layer to a rectangle that's the full size of the image, the system will animate the change for you.

Comment: The tricky part with this approach is creating the CAShapeLayer the size of the whole image.  I have the image scaled down, so I don't have the dimensions that it would be if it were not being cropped.  If I did, I could just animate the change in frame size with clipsToBounds=YES.

Comment: UIImage has a size property that will tell you the "native" size of the image. Unless you've created a scaled version of the image, it you should be able to check the image's size property.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 21st 2019, it seems like the `masksToBounds` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410896-maskstobounds) is just wrong. `masksToBounds` does not seem to be animatable. I have tried animating masksToBounds with CABasicAnimation and CAKeyframeAnimations and it doesn't seem to work.